# what is the correct syntax for creating a database trigger for insert, modify and delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

i have what seems like a basic scenario for a db trigger in SQL server and i am running into an issue.

i have table  **Users** (id, name, phone, etc) and i have tables **UsersHistory** (id, user_id action, fields, timestamp)

i want a database trigger where anytime inserts, updates or deletes into Users, i want a new record created in UsersHistory with the user id and the action that was done (insert new, updated fields, deleted id.  Basically an audit log table.

this is how far i got, but i can't figure out how to:

1. Get the id on modify and deletes and also
2. How to get a list of fields that have changed and the action that was committed (insert, delete, update)

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Users_History 
   ON  Users
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
 AS 
 BEGIN
-- Insert statements for trigger here

insert into UsersHistory (user_id, [action], [fields], timestamp)
select  max(id) as user_id, {action ??},{fields??}  getdate() from Users)

END
GO
```

any suggestions?

Comment: no, you shouldn't depend on the underlying "Users" table - you need to make sure to use the `Inserted` and `Deleted` "pseudo-tables" that are available in the trigger body

Comment: Also, you seem to believe the trigger will be called once for each INSERT or UPDATE - that is **NOT** the case. If you UPDATE a whole bunch of rows (20, 50 rows), it will be called exactly ONCE for the operation (with the Inserted and Deleted tables holding 50 rows each).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest might be to just simply create three triggers - one for each operation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUserInsert
ON dbo.User AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.UserHistory............
END     

CREATE TRIGGER trgUserDelete
ON dbo.User AFTER DELETE
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.UserHistory............
END 

CREATE TRIGGER trgUserUpdate
ON dbo.User AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.UserHistory............
END
```

That way, things are simple and you easily understand what you're doing, plus it gives you the ability to turn off a trigger for a single operation, if you e.g. need to insert or delete a huge list of items.

Inside the trigger, you have two "pseudo-tables" - `Inserted` (for INSERT and UPDATE) and `Deleted` (for UPDATE and DELETE). These pseudo tables contain the values for the newly inserted values (or the updated ones in UPDATE), or the ones that were deleted (for DELETE) or have been updated (the old values, before the update, for the UPDATE operation).

You need to be aware that a trigger will be called once even if you update a huge number of rows, e.g. `Inserted` and `Deleted` will typically contain multiple rows.

As a sample, you could write a "AFTER INSERT" trigger like this (just guessing what your table structure might be....):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUserInsert
ON dbo.User AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO 
      dbo.UserHistory(UserID, Action, DateTimeStamp, AuditMessage)
      SELECT 
         i.UserID, 'INSERT', getdate(), 'User inserted into table'
      FROM
         Inserted i
END
```

You are looking for a way to find out which "action" this trigger caused? I don't see any way to do this - another reason to keep the three trigger separate. The only way to find this out would be to count the rows in the `Inserted` and `Updated` tables:

- if both counts are larger than zero, it's an `UPDATE`
- if the `Inserted` table has rows, but the `Deleted` does not, it's an `INSERT`
- if the `Inserted` table has no rows, but the `Deleted` does, it's a `DELETE`

You're also looking for a "list of fields that were updated" - again, you won't have any simple solution, really. You could either just loop through the fields in the "Users" table that are of interest, and check

```
IF UPDATE(fieldname) ......
```

but that gets a bit tedious.

Or you could use the [`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) function - this however doesn't give you a nice list of column names, but a VARBINARY in which each column is basically one bit, and if it's turned on, that column was updated. Not very easy to use.....

---

If you really want to create a single, big trigger, this could serve as a basis - it detects what operation has caused the trigger to fire, and will insert entries into your User_History table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUser_Universal
ON dbo.Users
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @InsHasRows BIT = 0
  DECLARE @DelHasRows BIT = 0

  IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM INSERTED)
    SET @InsHasRows = 1

  IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DELETED)
    SET @DelHasRows = 1

  DECLARE @TriggerAction VARCHAR(20)

  IF @InsHasRows = 1 AND @DelHasRows = 1 
     SET @TriggerAction = 'UPDATE'
  ELSE
     IF @InsHasRows = 1
        SET @TriggerAction = 'INSERT'
     ELSE  
        SET @TriggerAction = 'DELETE'

  IF @InsHasRows = 1
    INSERT INTO dbo.UsersHistory(user_id, [action], [fields], timestamp)
      SELECT i.UserId, @TriggerAction, null, getdate()
      FROM INSERTED i
  ELSE  
    INSERT INTO dbo.UsersHistory(user_id, [action], [fields], timestamp)
      SELECT d.UserId, @TriggerAction, null, getdate()
      FROM DELETED d
END
```

I haven't included the figuring out which fields have been updated part just yet - that's left as an exercise to the reader :-)

---

Does that help at all?

Comment: I definitely agree with keeping them separate, makes things much easier to handle. +1

Comment: One small niggling issue here: What happens if the operation is a `MERGE`?  There may be updates and inserts, but I think this trigger would end up flagging them all as `UPDATE`.

Comment: @aaronaught: good question - the MERGE is broken into individual operations (INSERT, UPDATES, DELETES), but I quite honestly don't know what they'd end up looking like in the trigger. I agree most likely it would be a UPDATE since you most likely will have some inserted and some deleted rows

Answer (score 2):

There are two "tables" that are used in the trigger. One is `DELETED` and one is `INSERTED`. When you delete a row, that row is captured in the `DELETED` table. When you insert a row, that row is captured in the `INSERTED` table. When you update a row, the old row is in the `DELETED` table, and the new row is in the `INSERTED` table. The `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables have the same schema as the table on which you are adding the trigger.

You might check out [this solution](http://maxaffinity.blogspot.com/2008/03/auditing-your-tables.html) that will create a query for you that will make all the auditing triggers you want, as well as the table in which to store the audits, excluding any selected tables. It will only do `UPDATE` triggers, but could easily be modified to make `INSERT` and `DELETE` triggers as well.