# Create database trigger, to audit insert on all tables in SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

My requirement is to create a database trigger to track all the changes happening on each tables under this database.

I noticed that create database trigger having options to track changes on database level but not on each table level.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Have you tried these?
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-Audit-Table-and-5cd69d5d

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess what you are looking for is creating audit tables for every DML(update, insert, delete) event in that database, so you can do that like in this example for each table:

[what is the correct syntax for creating a database trigger for insert, modify and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014640/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-creating-a-database-trigger-for-insert-modify-an)

Or you can use this SP that creates Audit Table and Insert\Update\Delete Triggers for a given table. Just retrieve all the tables in db with a simple script like this, put them in a temp table and loop through that table to create audit table and triggers:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-Audit-Table-and-5cd69d5d

```
   DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(100)
   DECLARE @Schema_Name VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as SchemaName,name as TableName
    INTO #Temp
    FROM sys.tables 

    While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Table_Name = TableName From #Temp
    Select Top 1 @Schema_Name = SchemaName From #Temp   
    EXEC GenerateTriggers @Schemaname = @Schema_Name,@Tablename  = @Table_Name, @GenerateScriptOnly = 1

    Delete #Temp Where TableName= @Table_Name and SchemaName = @Schema_Name

End
```